# JSP/Tomcat secure login with sessionstorage

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-security, struts, httpsession

I have a system running on Tomcat, with HTML/JSP in front-end, and java/Spring/Struts in backend.

I made a login-feature where the user enters his username and password.
In backend, I validate the username and password to the stored user in DB.
If match, I store the username in HTTPsession:

```
         session.setAttribute( "username", name );
```

Then, on every class-action in backend, I add the following code:

```
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    if(session.getAttribute("username") == null) {
        return mapping.findForward("invalidUser");
    }
```

the invalidUSer-mapping redirects the user back to the login-page.

1. How secure is this?
2. Is there a way to check the httpsession without adding my validation-code to every class?
3. Do you guys have tips (or examples/tutorials) on how to do this differently? The system is already created and in production, so I do not want to do too many architecural changes.

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using Spring in your project, you may want to look into [Spring Security](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/) to replace your bespoke security mechanisms. You can configure it to protect certain resources within your application, authenticate against bespoke database back-ends, LDAP directories, etc. This will allow you to remove all manual checking of the session to see if the user is authenticated, and will redirect anonymous users to the specified login page when they attempt to access protected resources.

Along with the spring security filter definition in web.xml, the configuration can be specified in a single spring-security.xml file (imported into your root app config) using the **security:http** namespace to define the login page, protected resources, logout page, security headers etc. You could use a org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.**JdbcDaoImpl** instance configured as a bean to define the user service which can be referenced by the **authentication-provider** - see the docs, its very flexible.

Hope that's useful.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The link you posted does not work, do you have another link?

Comment: @TorK - huh, that's weird - works for me. Here's the URL: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/

Comment: @TorK - just to add, that link's for the current release v3.2.5. The main Spring docs homepage (http://spring.io/docs) has links for the very latest versions of each Spring module (reference docs and APIs)